# Choosing between and properly interpreting Analysis of Variance vs Wilcoxon rank sum test

Tags: r, anova, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test

(Newb on this, so please assume good faith but low skill)

I have this set of data where I'm interested in whether there is a significant and meaningful difference in `consumption` (measured in local currency) per person based on whether the person `didread` a piece of information.

```
> summary(df)
 didread    consumption      
 0:20295   Min.   :    0.00  
 1: 5518   1st Qu.:   40.19  
           Median :  108.42  
           Mean   :  194.36  
           3rd Qu.:  227.23  
           Max.   :13245.55
> sd(df$consumption)
[1] 330.9634
```

The distribution of `consumption` is highly skewed. The density chart of `log10(consumption + 1)`, grouped by `didread` shows

[image]

Now, an analysis of variance shows

```
> aov.out <- aov(log10(consumption + 1) ~ didread, data=df)
> summary(aov.out)
               Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value   Pr(>F)    
didread         1     19  19.375   31.99 1.56e-08 ***
Residuals   25811  15630   0.606                     
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
> TukeyHSD(aov.out)
  Tukey multiple comparisons of means
    95% family-wise confidence level

Fit: aov(formula = log10(consumption + 1) ~ didread, data = df)

$didread
           diff         lwr         upr p adj
1-0 -0.06682713 -0.08998316 -0.04367109     0
```

Also, trying a Wilcoxon rank sum test:

```
> with(df, wilcox.test(log10(consumption + 1) ~ didread, conf.int=TRUE))

    Wilcoxon rank sum test with continuity correction

data:  log10(consumption + 1) by didread
W = 60112000, p-value < 2.2e-16
alternative hypothesis: true location shift is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.04743923 0.08262361
sample estimates:
difference in location 
            0.06515087
```

Now for my questions:

- Am I in the right here in interpreting this as that both of these tests say that the individuals in the `didread == 1` group consumed `1 - exp(-0.066)` = 6% less than `didread == 0`?
- Which of the tests (`aov` vs `wilcox.test`) is more appropriate given these distributions? If I would like to report confidence intervals, which should I use?
- Are there any post-hoc tests I should consult in whether these results are meaningful, or is that a business decision from this point on?
- Anything else I should consider in this, to not make a fool out of myself?

## Edit 1: Venturing further into new territory; attempting to answer the "distribution of residuals" questions

Is this what @whuber is asking about?

```
df.lm <- with(subset(df, consumption > 0), lm(log10(consumption) ~ didread))
summary(df.lm)
data.stdres=rstandard(df.lm)
qqnorm(data.stdres)
qqline(data.stdres)
```

[image]

Comment: The distribution of consumption is irrelevant to your problem. Of concern is the distribution of the regression (or ANOVA) *residuals.*  What does that distribution look like?

Comment: @whuber like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The interpretation is a percent change, but not exactly what you gave. The tests give the difference between $didread_0$ and $didread_1$ so the model is similar to (pardon the notation please)

$$
log_{10}(consumption+1) = didread_0 + difference\\
consumption+1 = 10^{didread_0}10^{difference}
$$

The percent change of $(consumption+1)$ is

$10^{difference}=10^{-0.06682713}=0.8573791$.

This means that $didread_1$ is a 14.3% drop from $didread_0$. You can check this by comparing `mean(df[df$didread==1,]$consumption)` and `mean(df[df$didread==0,]$consumption) * 10^(-0.06682713)` which should be almost equal.

For the Wilcoxon test, it looks like the reference level was switched to $didread_1$. So there $didread_0$ has a $10^{0.06515087}=1.16$ or 16% increase from $didread_1$.

For the ANOVA test, the QQPlot is helpful and you can see some problems in one tail of the plot. There are also other [residual plots](http://docs.statwing.com/interpreting-residual-plots-to-improve-your-regression/) that you can [check for problems](http://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~stark/SticiGui/Text/regressionDiagnostics.htm). For the Wilcoxon test, it assumes independence of samples and that the only difference in (consumption) distributions is a shift in the means. This looks to be the case except for near zero where $didread_0$ is now left of $didread_1$ instead of right of it. With slight problems in both tests' assumptions, I don't see a clear winner. Personally, I think the Wilcoxon test's assumptions are better met and would go with that one.

When computing the confidence intervals, don't forget to transform properly. The 95% confidence interval for ANOVA would be

$
\Big[\big(1-10^{-0.08998316}\big),\big(1-10^{-0.04367109}\big)\Big] = [0.187, 0.096]
$

so $didread_1$ is 9.6% to 18.7% less consumption than $didread_0$. Again the Wilcoxon test is similar but in the reverse direction.

$
\Big[10^{0.04743923},10^{0.08262361}\Big] = [1.11, 1.21]
$

so $didread_0$ is 11% to 21% more consumption than $didread_1$